# Python: Replacing Text in all files of a nested folder

Tags: python, string, glob

I am trying to replace a string of text in all json files in a directory. Directory has several nested directories, depth of directory structure is not know. Below is my code, which is not replacing strings.

```
import os
import pathlib
import glob
def main():
    replacement =  "New"
    oldTex = "Old"
    baseFolder = '1.5.13_test_2'
    fullPath = "/Users/gfKron/path"

    for item in glob.glob(fullPath +"/*.json", recursive=True):
        temp = []
        with open(item, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                line.replace(oldTex, replacement)
                temp.append(line)
        with open(item, "w") as f:
            f.writelines(temp)
            f.close()
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help  is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` returns the replacement string

strings are immutable in python

```
temp.append(line.replace(oldTex, replacement))
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai.  Is recursion logic true as well ?